# Custom Add-In Won't Load

Tags: vba, powerpoint, add-in

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUi-0wpMUHU&t=8s) but I don't know if this is outdated or some weird permissions going on. The load button is greyed out when I try to add my custom add-in.

I created a custom macro for exporting PNG files. I saved the .pptm file and exported the add-in file.

I installed the RibbonX Editor and the XML code to add the macro to the ribbon. When I open a blank file, go to File>Options>Add-ins>PowerPoint Add-ins>Select my ExportPNG Macro, the load button is greyed out. I press close and my custom ribbon doesn't appear like the tutorial video.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Just trying to get my macro to be available for all PowerPoint files I open. On Windows 11 Pro 23H2, PowerPoint version 2310. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to make my vba sub public. It's now working on all PowerPoint files.